# Excel / VBA: auto-adjust column width after pasting data

Tags: excel, vba, column-width

I have a blank Excel table saved as a template into which I copy data from the clipboard (originating from a website).

Is there a way using VBA to auto-adjust the width of each column to its content after the data (text) has been pasted in ?

Edit: The data I paste will always be inserted starting from A1 and will always fill the same number of columns.

Comment: Yes you can. Try recording a macro whilst doing it which will give you an example.

Comment: Thanks. Just figured it out as well. :) How do I trigger the macro so that it runs after I pasted my data ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can do it with `AutoFit`:

```
 Columns("A:B").EntireColumn.AutoFit
```

Comment: Thanks ! Yes, that's what I just saw as well. :) How do I trigger the macro so that it runs after I pasted my data ?

Comment: Yes, no problem but what I mean is, is there a way to auto-run the macro after pasting using something like an onchange or onpaste event ?

Comment: @user2571510 You can make a button and always if you press the button the macro will start. Here is an example: http://www.mrexcel.com/tip068.shtml Is that what you need? :)

Comment: Thanks ! I know how to add a button but am looking for something to start the macro automatically when the table content changes, which is after I pasted my data.

Comment: Never mind. I figured it out - this can be done with the Worksheet_Change event.

Comment: Afterwards, you might want ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select to deselect the area.

Answer (score 14):

You can perform the following:

```
Columns("A").Autofit
```

Comment: Better than the accepted answer since it doesn't involve using (performance-killing) Select

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a worksheet change event, but if your worksheet is changed in any way after the paste, it runs again.  Not an issue unless you're trying to hide columns to focus on a subset of data because they will autofit themselves constantly.

I recommend using a button to paste the data and including the column width setting as part of the paste command.

Comment: Welcome to SO @Stephany. You are proposing a good approach and would help the questioner even more if you expand your answer with a workable example.