# EXCEL: Automatically auto-size column width upon pasting the data to excel

Tags: excel, automation, autosize

I know there are ways that I can manually autosize the column width (select all and then click on any column end, format> autosize etc) but i want to autosize the column width based on the data that i paste.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your question has been answered [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24058774/excel-vba-auto-adjust-column-width-after-pasting-data)

TLDR;

```
Columns("A:B").Select

Selection.EntireColumn.AutoFit
```

and use the `Worksheet_Change` event

Comment: If i use the below VB code it will then work as a charm but I will have the file to be stored in .dotm format correct?

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range) 
    
    Columns("A:B").Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.AutoFit

End Sub

Comment: You can remove macro on last save

Comment: any other way to do this? I might have to autosize multiple times by different people.